# Java Spring + Hibernate "Cannot add or update a child row"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ravermeister`.`artist_recordlabel`, CONSTRAINT `FK_9dgdyft45droyopxsqijwb1dx` FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`) REFERENCES `artist` (`id`))

Artist class

```
@Entity
@Repository
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "artist_firstname")
    private String artist_firstname;

    @Column(name = "artist_secondname")
    private String artist_secondname;

    @Column(name = "artist_nickname")
    private String artist_nickname;


    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "artist_recordlabel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"))
    private Set<RecordLabel> recordLabels;

    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable (name = "artist_musicrelease", joinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "artist_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn (name = "musicrelease_id"))
    private Set <MusicRelease> musicReleaseSet;
```

and RecordLabel class

```
@Entity
@Repository
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class RecordLabel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "label_name")
    private String label_name;

    @Column(name = "label_country")
    private String label_country;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "artist_recordlabel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id"))
    private Set<Artist> artistsList;
```

Comment: Your question was marked of being "very low quality", please provide more context and details for the code you posted, e.g. what entities you have and what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this guide for a many-to-many relation

http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

I think this error means that you are trying to insert/update into RecordLabel table a `artist_id` value that does not exist in Artist table.